# Center flex items when they wrap (no media queries) whereas they start with space-between alignement

Tags: css, flexbox

Below you will see what I have. When it wraps with responsive, I would `.image` and `.content` boxes align center. It's important to keep `.image` on the left and `.content` on the right on larger viewport.

Any idea ?

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.content{}

.list{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="image">
Image
</div>
<div class="content">
<ul class="list">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Can you please be a bit more clear with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's just alignement I want to fix. On large screen I want elements with space between and when it wraps on smaller screen I want each element center horizontally on their rows.

Comment: @chles you can use media query

Comment: I update my question. I want this behavior auto because I don't know width of each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to achive responsiveness

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .container {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: I update my question. I want this behavior auto because I don't know width of each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css for mobile devices

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   .container {
      justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: I update my question. I want this behavior auto because I don't know width of each element.